# Where can I report a cryptocurrency fraud?

Tags: united-states, scams, fees, cryptocurrency

I am positive that I have been taken in a wild chase to get my money back in a cryptocurrency advanced fee scam, and I have reported this to google, WhatsApp, ic3, Coinbase, etc., and I am not getting any response.  I have called the FBI and I can’t get through.

Each time I am asked to pay a new fee to get my money back and they won’t deduct it from my earnings or my money back.

I know the “names” of these people with IDs, US phone numbers used, emails, so called financial institutions, and in which country the “payout manager” is.  I have all the emails, text, screenshots, etc. of my proof that this has been a phishing scam.  I wish I could have known earlier what all this was, but I didn't.

I just need to know where I can get results on getting these people caught, even though I know I will most likely not get my money back.  Better is to avoid anyone else getting scammed out of their money.

Comment: Note that one of the claimed advantages of some forms of crypto is precisely that it is difficult to trace the transactions -- and odds are that any phone numbers, accounts, or names you dealt with were discarded after you stopped paying. Odds of anyone being able to use your info to find the crooks are not great.

Comment: "Cryptocurrency fraud" is a redundancy; it's vanishingly rare for crypto to ever produce anything non-scammy.  There's no need to report it; everyone you might want to report it *to* already knows.

Answer (score 58):

> Each time I am asked to pay a new fee to get my money back and they won’t deduct it from my earnings or my money back.

Stop doing this. You won't get any earnings, you're just giving more money to the criminals.

The [IC3](https://www.ic3.gov/) is the right place. [IC3 is the FBI](https://www.ic3.gov/). While they will unlikely to respond to your individual complaint, they work well by aggregating information and following patterns.

You can read more about how to avoid scams and how to report them on the [FTC website](https://consumer.ftc.gov/articles/what-know-about-cryptocurrency-and-scams).

> I know the “names” of these people with ID’s, US phone numbers used, emails, so called financial institutions, and in which country the “payout manager” is. I have all the emails, text, screenshots, etc. of my proof that this has been a phishing scam. I wish I would of known earlier what all this was but I wasn’t.

I doubt any of this information is actually factually correct and real. These people operate with stolen identities and forged documents to create a whole web of "alternative reality".

Report everything you have to IC3, however don't expect to recover anything or hear back. The money you paid into the scam is very likely lost and will never be recovered. However, with your report, the FBI may be able to identify who these people *really* are and find a way to stop them. While you may not hear about your specific case, you may read [news reports like these](https://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/two-estonian-citizens-arrested-575-million-cryptocurrency-fraud-and-money-laundering-scheme), which are based on the information provided in complaints such as yours.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142843/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-where-can-i-report-a-cryptocurrency-phishing-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.